# index out of range with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, indexoutofrangeexception

I tried to understand this nasty index out of range error for some time but I can not figure out why it shows up.

The output is what I am expecting with a correct number of results.
I cannot catch the empty one that I guess it raising the error.

In the code below I tried to capture the error but I must to something wrong.
I tried as well the len() method.
I'm counting the number of iteration as well.

```
#Import lib needed
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#-----------------------------------------Importing data -----------------------------------------------------------------#
#Page with number of adds per location

my_url_nb_Nimes_building = 'https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/?th=1&q=immeuble&it=1&location=N%EEmes&ret=1&ret=2&ret=5'
#Opening connection, grabbing the page, close connection
uClientnimesbuild = uReq(my_url_nb_Nimes_building)
page_htmlnimesbuild =  uClientnimesbuild.read()
uClientnimesbuild.close()

page_soupnimesbuild = soup(page_htmlnimesbuild, "html.parser")


containglobalnbnimesbuild = ((page_soupnimesbuild).find_all("section",{"class":"item_infos"}))


count = 0
for contain in containglobalnbnimesbuild:
    try:
        titlecontain = contain.find_all("h2",{"class":"item_title"})
        title = titlecontain[0]
        print("Titre:", title)
        count = count +1
        print(count)
    except ValueError:
        print("inerror")
```

Would you have any idea what I am doing wrong to catch this.

```
    title = titlecontain[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Since your except statement is specifically catching a `ValueError`, and the invalid access to `titlecontain` is giving you an `IndexError`, the error isn't being caught. You could change your code to say `except IndexError` instead, or just `except` and that should catch the error.

You might also just want to use an if statement. Something like

```
if len(titlecontain) == 0:
    continue
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Indeed I manage to catch the line and get into the the correct loop
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i got it working like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website_url = 'https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/?th=1&q=immeuble&it=1&location=N%EEmes&ret=1&ret=2&ret=5'
page = requests.get(website_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')

section = soup.find("section",{"class":"tabsContent block-white dontSwitch"})

for t in section.find_all("h2",{"class":"item_title"}):
    try:
        print(t.text.strip())
    except ValueError:
        print("inerror")
```

Comment: I change back lxml to html.parser to ake it work for me but yes you do not have any index error. 
I need to understand how so and the requests lib. 

You use a different find section from me that I need to check as well.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think it happened because in your first markup "containglobalnbnimesbuild" you use "find_all"  - this means find_all will return an array if this element is more than once on the page. Then you go ahead and loop through that array and for each array you try to find the h2 tags. It would probably work fine if you make 2 for loops. one for "containglobalnbnimesbuild" and one nested loop for "titlecontain" - but it is just a blind guess without checking

Comment: I think you right indeed.
For I have managed to handle all error and get the output wanted.
Big thanks